# TVirtualStringTree: Check if node in rendered area

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I'm trying to find out if a `TVirtualStringTree` Node is actually being rendered, or outside of the visible tree area altogether.

Obviously, this is something entirely different than `.Visible`.

Why do i need this:
My AfterCellPaint paints various components on top of the cells.
I check the visibility of the Node cells' TRects against the components' positions. That's all fine, except for the case when the tree gets scrolled by a large amount at once. For example, when I click into the non-slider part of the scrollbar, it will jump. The AfterCellPaint that adjusts the visibility will not get called, therefor the components visibility is not adjusted. I'm looking for a bullet-proof method to adjust the components' visibility.

Comment: Val, that was exactly what i was looking for, thanks. I just didn't find the right search terms to stumble upon that.